# why on my live environment users will be logged-out if i do an application pool recycle , while on my test environment it is not the case

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, forms-authentication, iis-8

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application, hosted inside IIS-8 and windows server 2012 r2. now i have the same settings inside my live and my test server. Here is the application pool, settings inside my test:-

[image]

and inside live:-
[image]

now i am using form authentication inside my asp.net mvc web application, here is the related web.config entities:-

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add name="TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, &#xA;            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionUsername="*********" connectionPassword="******" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />

  </providers>
</membership>

<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="40320" />
</authentication>
```

now i have noted this strange behavior. if i am on the test server and i right click on the "application pool >> Recycle" , then logged-in users will not be logged-out. even if i restart the whole test server OS, users will not get affected. while on live server if i chnage any setting inside the application pool such as changing the recycle time interval , or i manually recycle the live application pool,, then logged-in users will be logged-out when they try to access the web application .. so not sure what is controlling this ? is there settings out side iis that can control this ? seems on test server nothing will force logged-in user to be logout , while on live changing the application pool recycle interval, or doing iis reset will force logged-in user to be logged-out..

Comment: Take a look to the session mode. By default, session mode is "InProc". So, when the app pool is recycled the session server is recycled too. Configure something else than InProc on your "live environment".

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ where i can find the session mode ?

Comment: In "Session State", when you have selected your site in IIS Manager. Take a look to this page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725582(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ both test & live have the state mode = in process..

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ can you adivce more on this seems both servers have their state mode= in process... so seems there is something else , causing the differences ..

Comment: Did you check on website/application/virtual folder ? Because if you have selected the server you may have a different result.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ not sure i got your point.. can you adivce more on this?